# Killing Internet Explorer results in Crash Recovery prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, kill

I'm currently working on an application that uses an embedded internet explorer browser.
The application is written in C# in visual studio 2010. IE is IE9, but the problem also occurs in previous versions of IE.

The application is based on Oracle Customer On Demand, but is a standalone application that uses the embedded browser and adds some extensions to it.

Now the problem is, whenever I close my application, and open IE, IE tells me: -Your last browsing session closed unexpectedly. And it wants to reopen the page used in my application.

How can I prevent this? I know I can turn off "enable automatic crash recovery" but I don't think this is a clean solution. Is there a way to close IE from inside Visual studio properly?

At the moment it gets closed by doing:

```
foreach ( var ieProcessId in this.ieProcessIds )
{
    Process.GetProcessById(ieProcessId).Close();
    Process.GetProcessById(ieProcessId).Kill();
}
```

Comment: can't you access that embeded IE object and call kind of Close/Dispose/Terminate whatever method before exit?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what he's meant to do. I'm not sure why it's surprising that crashing IE triggers a crash recovery prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Kill() it's immediate stop (when application can't save own resoults).

Try more gently CloseMainWindow().